# Error with jsPDF: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file”

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

I have this error when trying to pass Image data to addImage function, I tried to downgrade the jspdf and html2canvas versions but this still happens,
i tried to import the two libraries in many different ways but i'm still facing this problem

and this is my code

```
  export() {
    console.log('printing');
    const data = document.getElementById('reportContent');
    this.generatePDF(data);
  }

  generatePDF(htmlContent) {
    html2canvas(htmlContent).then(canvas => {
      const imgWidth = 290;
      const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width);
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');
      const position = 10;
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      pdf.save('report.pdf');
    });
  }
```

and this is HTML

```
    <div #reportContent style="display: none;" id = "reportContent"> 
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="color: red;background-color: blue;">1111
          </td>
          <td>2222
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, it happened because of using
`display:none;`
inside HTML
I had updated this function like that:

```
  export() {
    console.log('printing');
    const data = document.getElementById('reportContent');
    data.style.display = "block";
    this.generatePDF(data);
    data.style.display = "none";
  }
```

You can't print a hidden Canvas.